# Showing "Subscriber" Posts And User's Own Posts

Tags: php, mysql, sql, posts

This has stumped me for some time.

My problem:
I have 2 different tables.. A table for user posts and a table for subscribers.

The subscribers table looks like this:

SubscriberID -> ProfileID 
1 -> 2 
1 -> 3 
2 -> 3 
2 -> 4 
3 -> 2

My posts table looks like this: 
PostID -> AuthorID -> PostDate -> PostBody 
1 -> 2 -> 12/20/12 -> Hello Word 
2 -> 3 -> 12/21/12 -> Bye Bye World 
3 -> 1 -> 12/22/12 -> Oh Wait 
4 -> 4 -> 12/23/12 -> Is anyone still here?

Basically, how it works is that the user with the ID is subscribed to the user with the ID 2 and 3. ID #2 is subscribed to ID #3 and #4. If a user is subscribed to a certain user, they can see only posts from the person they subscribed to. Now, I'm using the following I saw in a similar question:

```
SELECT POSTS.*
FROM POSTS
JOIN SUBSCRIBERS
ON POSTS.AUTHORID = SUBSCRIBERS.PROFILEID
WHERE SUBSCRIBERS.SUBSCRIBERID = ?
ORDER BY POSTS.POSTID DESC LIMIT 10
```

This works fine, but it does not show the user's post as well. I've tried modifying it, but it's not working :\

If you're wondering, the "?" represents the user's ID

So if you can, it would be great if someone could tell me how to include the user's own posts alongside with the posts from the people the user subscribes to

Comment: The simplest method is to allow users to subscribe to themselves (which makes sense given your model of showing subscribed posts).

Comment: Doing that is probably going to be my last resort if nothing else works

Comment: The alternative I can see is to use subqueries or multiple queries. Find your list of profileID's a user is subscribed to, then pull a list of posts where profileID is in the list of results, or is the current profileID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it modifying your query to :

```
SELECT POSTS.*
FROM POSTS
LEFT JOIN SUBSCRIBERS
ON POSTS.AUTHORID = SUBSCRIBERS.PROFILEID
WHERE SUBSCRIBERS.SUBSCRIBERID = ? OR POSTS.AUTHORID = ?
GROUP BY POSTS.POSTID ORDER BY POSTS.POSTID DESC LIMIT 10
```

It selects the user own posts as well. Hope this would help.

Updated : Added `GROUP BY POSTS.POSTID` so duplicates are removed as you only look for data in `POSTS` table.

When you run query like passing values- Eg. for user having id 1 the query looks like :

```
SELECT POSTS.*
FROM POSTS
LEFT JOIN SUBSCRIBERS
ON POSTS.AUTHORID = SUBSCRIBERS.PROFILEID
WHERE SUBSCRIBERS.SUBSCRIBERID = 1 OR POSTS.AUTHORID = 1 GROUP BY POSTS.POSTID
ORDER BY POSTS.POSTID DESC LIMIT 10
```

Results are :

```
PostID  AuthorID    PostDate    PostBody

3       1   2012-12-21  Oh Wait
2       3   2012-12-21  Bye Bye World
1       2   2012-12-20  Hello Word
```

This is what you get when pass values to the select query properly. The values passed to `SUBSCRIBERID` and `AUTHORID` **should** be same. The LEFT JOIN would fix your problem.

Comment: I'm not an SQL expert, but I'd say it might be because you're joining AuthorID with ProfileID so without testing I assume this means at least one person must be subscribed to the user for their AuthorID/ProfileID to be listed in the joined table.

Comment: @user984935 - The query is working properly and I have tested it with data you have posted in the question. You have to pass same id to `SUBSCRIBERID` and `AUTHORID` as in my updated query in the latter part of the answer.

Comment: @user984935 Make sure you are passing in the correct amount of parameters when executing the prepared statement.

Comment: While this works, It's not showing the posts from the user with the ID 1, but it does however show posts from the users they subscribe to.

Comment: Ok, I tried this code again but in the Subscribers table, I inserted ID 4 to subscribe to ID 1, and strangely enough, ID1's own posts started showing up. It appears the user has to have at least one subscriber in order to see there own posts.. Which of course I really don't want :S

Comment: @InVert - I'm sorry for misunderstanding your problem. The `LEFT JOIN` would fix your problem. I just updated the post.