# mysql combine 3 tables to get post of user and those that are followed

Tags: mysql, join

i have 3 tables users, stream and follow

follow table:

```
follow_id   user_id_follower   user_id_followed
    1              9                  2 
    2              9                  4
```

users table

```
id   username   
1     test1         
2     test2
```

stream table

```
id user_id  post_content    post_image   
1     9     Hi there        uploads/1.jpg
2     9     Another         uploads/2.jpg
```

this gives the user posts

```
SELECT users.username, stream.post_content, stream.post_image 
FROM users INNER JOIN stream ON users.id=stream.user_id 
WHERE stream.user_id = 9
```

this gives the people who user follows posts

```
SELECT users.username, stream.post_content, stream.post_image, 
follow.user_id_follower, follow.user_id_followed FROM follow
INNER JOIN stream ON follow.user_id_followed = stream.user_id
INNER JOIN users ON follow.user_id_followed = users.id
WHERE follow.user_id_follower = 9 // this change depending on user
```

I am having problem in making a single SQL statement that gets both user and followed posts

Comment: I need the query to get posts of both the user and those that he follows there are 2 queries there so I thought this was implied

Comment: Rachcha thanks your answer was right used union all and filled missing columns with blanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584224/showing-subscriber-posts-and-users-own-posts check this link solves the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `UNION ALL` for this.

```
SELECT s.*, follower.username, 1 order_priority
  FROM stream s
  JOIN user follower ON s.user_id = follower.userid
 WHERE follower.user_id = 9
UNION ALL
SELECT s.*, following.username, 2
  FROM stream s
  JOIN user following ON s.user_id = following.userid
  JOIN follow f ON following.user_id = f.user_id_followed
       AND f.user_id_follower = 9
ORDER BY order_priority;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the query you are looking for??

```
SELECT users.username, stream.post_content, stream.post_image, 
follow.user_id_follower, follow.user_id_followed FROM follow
INNER JOIN stream ON follow.user_id_followed = stream.id
INNER JOIN users ON follow.user_id_followed = users.id
WHERE follow.user_id_follower = 9;
```

Comment: No, this is not the solution. He is looking for both- posts by the user and posts by the people he's following. This will just give results for posts that the user is following. Please read other answers before you post your own.